# Wave function for particle in an infinite well located at $a$ and $b$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

I know that the wave function for a particle in a infinite potential well located between $0$ and $L$ is:

$$\psi_n = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}$$

But I don't have idea how to apply boundary conditions when the two walls aren't at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the walls are at a and b, the general solution to the equation is $\psi_n(x) = A\cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{b-a}\right)}+B\sin{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{b-a}\right)}$. Then you have to apply the boundary conditions $\psi_n(a)=\psi_n(b)=0$, which gives you a system of equations that you have to solve with algebra and trigonometry. But what the above answer put forward is true, given $L = b-a$ you just need to shift the trig function by a constant phase to satisfy the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

We can just translate everything by $a$ to the right:
$$\psi(x)~=~\psi_{old}(x-a)$$